# How to delete all documents with safe mode?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

remove() method without any argument removes all documents inside the collection.

```
$this->db->$collection->remove();
```

But how to remove all documents with safe mode?

What should be the first argument of remove?
passing array('safe' => true) as first argument doesn't delete all document because it's treated like a filter with key 'safe'.

```
$this->db->$collection->remove(array('safe' => true));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass that as second parameter in the remove call :

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php

```
$this->db->$collection->remove(array(),array('safe' => true));
```